# How can I make a div stretch to fit the height of a textarea?

Tags: css, html

I have the following:

```
        <div id="tab-notes" class="clearfix">
                <textarea cols=100 rows=15 class="full-width" id="dialogNotes" name="Pages">@Model.Notes</textarea>
        </div>
```

I have added a clearfix class but it seems that the DIV does not stretch to fit the height of the textarea. Is there something simple that I am missing?

```
.clearfix:after, .block-controls:after, .side-tabs:after {
    clear: both;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
}
```

Comment: please also post _all_ relevant css for that snippet.

Comment: have you set the height of the div manually?

Comment: There's no CSS for anything except the clearfix. I will post that.

Comment: as you can see from my answer, this isn't possible. please try to recreate your problem on jsfiddle and post a link - it's impossible to say whats wrong here without a possibility to simulate the problem. additional questions: do you get the same problem in every major browser (IE7/8/9 and up to date versions of Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari) or just in one of them?

Answer (score 1):

giving your `#tab-notes` a `background-color` you'll see that it *does* stretch to the textareas high (like it should) if there really aren't any other css-rules that affect these elements.

you can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mqke4/

the clearsfix seems to be senseless just given this snippet and doesn't change anything ( http://jsfiddle.net/Mqke4/1/ ). given this, there must be styles defined for `.full-width`, `#tab-notes`, `#dialogNotes` (or anything like that) causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is your textarea applied with `float: left` or `float: right` ?

If so, remove the float property from textarea.

But if you have to use that property,
the easiest way to solve the problem is to also apply the `float:` to your div too.

Or you can change the display type of your div to block by using `display: block`

There's more way to solve this problem.
But I think these are the easiest ones.